# Deleting rows of table in pages as well as records in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
$model_no=$row['model_no'];
echo $model_no;
mysql_query("delete * from nokia where model_no=$model_no");
}
else
{
}
?>




<?php
$sql="select * from nokia";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
?>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td style="border:thin solid;">Image</td>
 <td style="border:thin solid;">Model name</td>
 <td style="border:thin solid;">Action</td>
 </tr>
 <?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$img=$row['images1'];
$img1=$row['images2'];  
?>
<tr>

  <td  style="border:thin solid;"><?php echo "<a href='../images/".$img1."'><img  src='../images/".$img."' style='width:100px; height:100px;'/></a>" ?></td>
  <td style="color:#06F; font-size:18px; border:thin solid;"><?php echo $row['model_no']; ?></td>
  <td  style="border:thin solid;">
  <form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" value="Delete"   style="border:none;background:#06F;color:#FFF;  padding:5px; cursor:pointer;" name="delete"/>   
 </form></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

here i have fetched all the data from a database that has a nokia table and kept it in tabular form with each rows containing one delete button. Now when the delete button is clicked, i want the specific rows to be deleted on the page as well as in the database. i can't figure out the coding. please help.

Comment: You need to add `$row['model_no']` to your Delete button form, typically as a hidden input, and then get the posted value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `$row['model_no']` to your form, so it is not posting to be deleted.

Create a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['model_no']; ?>" name="model_no" />
```

and add it to your form

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['model_no']; ?>" name="model_no" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Delete"   style="border:none;background:#06F;color:#FFF;  padding:5px; cursor:pointer;" name="delete"/>   
</form>
```

Then on post check for the value

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
$model_no=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['model_no']);
echo $model_no;
mysql_query("delete * from nokia where model_no=$model_no");
}
?>
```